# std::filesystem::relative bug in Mingw or msvc?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, mingw, std-filesystem

I have the following code snipped, which produces the following output on mingw(gcc) and msvc:

```
std::cout << std::filesystem::relative("D:/home/freddy", "C:/home") << std::endl;
```

mingw(gcc):

```
"\\home\\freddy"
```

msvc:

```
""
```

gcc and also clang (both executed on linux):

```
"../../D:/home/freddy"
```

In my opinion it should be `""` or `"../../D:/home/freddy"`, since there is no relative path over root_paths, but not the relative path of an erased root path.

Additionally MSVC will fail, when the drive does not exist, because the drive is "not ready yet":
`weakly_canonical: Das Gerõt ist nicht bereit.: "D:/home/freddy"`
Which also seems like a MSVC bug in `std::filesystem::weakly_canonical`

Comment: Note: I find that [`std::filesystem::path::lexically_relative`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path/lexically_normal) is generally what we want it those case (no check of symlink, existance of path, ... (`D:\` currently might be alias/virtual drive to `C:\`)).

Comment: @Jarod42 Regardless of what you prefer, OP is still seeing inconsistent results with `std::filesystem::relative`.

Comment: No I want std::filesystem::relative, since it can be resolve symlinks if there are some. But normally std::filesystem::weakly_canonical should not fail in such a case:
"Returns a path composed by operator/= from the result of calling canonical() with a path argument composed of the leading elements of p that exist (as determined by status(p) or status(p, ec)), if any, followed by the elements of p that do not exist, if any."

Since D:/ is a Path which does not exist, it should be just appended.
But as @JesperJuhl said this is mostly for the std::filesystem::relative inconsistency.

Comment: I'm not sure what you would expect to happen, it's not clear from your question. In any case, this might be a bug (an unsupported corner case) in the standard library implementation.

Comment: 1) On Windows, `"C:/home"` is incorrect. It should be `"C:\\home"`. 2) `"../../D:/home/freddy"` is an impossible path, as drive letter must be at the beginning. 3) A cross-disk relative path does not exist. So `""` is the only possibility.

Comment: Ok I think this is a layer 8 problem or it got fixed with a mingw update. But the mingw and the MSVC implementation still differ when one of the Driveletters is not used.